# Get max memory used in last 24 hours in Prometheus

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus

I am using kubernetes and prometheus. I am using node js server. I want to get max memory used in last 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I have used these queries for getting memory used:

Stored custom rule for summing the memory used by cluster:

`cluster:memory_used:bytes =
      sum by (cluster) (
        node_memory_MemTotal
      ) - sum by (cluster) (
        node_memory_MemFree
      ) - sum by (cluster) (
        node_memory_Buffers
      ) - sum by (cluster) (
        node_memory_Cached
      )`

Then, I have queried the prometheus HTTP API: 
`/api/v1/query?query=cluster:max_memory_used:bytes`

I can get `timestamp` of the `max_memory_used. So, for that particular data point, I can also get other metrics.